# Discontinuous covariance kernels

Tags: probability, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $I$ be a topological space, and let $c : I \times I \to \mathbb S$ denote a symmetric, nonnegative-definite function.

Must $c$ be continuous with respect to the topology of $I$, or is it possible for $c$ to be discontinuous?

Answer (score 0):

Trivially, let $I$ be equipped with the coarse topology, and let $c$ be non-constant. Then $c$ is not continuous.

I'll need to think about the precise assumption I'm after.